# Search for character or string in one column and auto fill in following column

Tags: excel

My apologies if this question has been answered I tried searching for a bit and didnt find a solution.  So I've been tasked to add a description column to a large spreadsheet of codes.  There are about 11,000 rows and I'll have to add the description columns myself for each code column.  As an example I've taken a screenshot of my first code column.  So for this example there are 3 code options P,U, E.  I would like to be able to auto populate the 2nd column based on the 3 options in the previous column and just drag that formula down instead of doing a ton of copy and pasting.  Any help is much appreciated![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbg8t.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `IF` formula. Provided the 'P', 'E' and 'U' values are in column A, use this formula in B2:

```
=IF(A2="P","Primary",IF(A2="E","Excess - un...",IF(A2="U","insert text here","")))
```

Its hard to write the complete formula when you haven't provided the three potential strings for the 2nd column.

Comment: Thank you!  your answer gave enough logic for me to fill it in! Thanks so much!